# AVG Oracle retornando valor muito quebrado

Tags: sql

Fala meus queridos, estou fazendo uma média no oracle com a função AVG...

```
select avg (checkd) from table
```

Só que as vezes retorna um numero muito quebrado, por exemplo 0.002298850574712643678160919540229885057471

como posso fazer para retornar um valor por exemplo 0.2 ... assim por diante.

Agradeço qualquer possível ajuda !

Comment: de 0.002 para 0.2 teria que multiplicar por 100...  mas como disse, se o problema é a quantidade de casas decimais, procure a função round

Comment: foi só um exemplo o 0,2, só quero que ele mostre um numero menor kk

Comment: só usar o round para arredondar, ou o trunc para truncar  o número

Comment: Pode me mostrar um exemplo fazendo favor ? sou novo com programação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e23381/row_functions101.htm#OLAXS495) e [round](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm).

O `trunc` corta o número até x dígitos.
O `round`  arredonda o número até x dígitos.

Você pode especificar quantos dígitos quer cortar/arredondar no segundo parâmetro da função.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT TRUNC(0.002298850574712643678160919540229885057471,4) truncado,
       ROUND(0.002298850574712643678160919540229885057471,4) arredondado
  FROM dual
```